# How to use correctly filtering on NightwatchJS

Tags: nightwatch.js

I'm using `src_folders` with filter to skip others .js files that don't match my patterns but he is skipping patterns files also:

[image: Imgur]

```
Error: No tests defined! using source folder: test_fixtures
   - using path filter: /*-spec.js
```

Comment: have you tried with `filter: ["./*-spec.js*"]` ?

Comment: Yeah, dont worked

Answer (score 1):

```
"src_folders" : ["test_fixtures"],
```

and

```
 "filter": "**/*-spec.js",
```

works for me. Now i get all files located in test_fixtures/**/*-spec.js